# Запретить метки предлогов, союзов, частиц и т.п

Tags: предложение, метки

По результатам вопроса [Why tag [a] is not allowed, but all other letters are allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298293/339911) на MSE выяснилось, что каждый сайт имеет возможность кастомизировать список запрещённых к использованию меток. Предлагаю нам внести в этот список метки, являющиеся по сути предлогами, союзами и частицами. Например, [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), [на](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0), [и](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8), [не](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5) и т.п. Для предупреждения случайного появления подобных меток.

Comment: Кстати, метка [tag:по] уже существует. И её хорошо бы выпилить.

Comment: Эдгар По с тобой не согласен!)

Comment: А вообще, "по" тут - это не предлог

Comment: @АлексейШиманский написано строчными буквами - значит предлог :)

Comment: Что, так опасны эти метки?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не особо, но и текущие запрещённые для нас не опасны.

Answer (score 5):

Чёрный список следует использовать, например, тогда, когда метку регулярно вычищают, но юзеры её упорно пересоздают. Превентивно забивать чёрный список всякими разными словами большой пользы нет. Как вам уже ответили на другом сайте, это не защита от букв, а защита от написания предложений в списке меток.

Если говорить про метку [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), то её надо вычистить не как предлог, а как мета-метку "программное обеспечение". После этого по вкусу можно занести метку в чёрный список, хотя при текущем потоке вопросов она и близко не приближается к какому-нибудь [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Comment: Наиболее очевидно, что `a` и `the` писали часто в метках на англо-сайтах, но все остальные типа `or`, `and`, `on`, о которых говорил Oded в своём ответе менее очевидны, но они тоже запрещены. Почему? Мне кажется, что до кучи, т.е. превентивно и на всякий случай. Почему бы и нам не сделать подобное? Это же не сложно, а хуже точно не станет.

Comment: @alexolut, потому что это не надо.