# Метка "Ошибка" и ее синонимы

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Удалите эти [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0). Вопросы все равно чистятся от них.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможны ли "служебные метки" с Меты (вроде \[важное\]) на основном сайте?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5789/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Может быть и не совсем дубликат, но проблему описывает ту же.

Comment: Нет, не думаю, что дубликат. Возможно, стоит эту метку вбросить в чёрный список. [tag:книги]-то должны продолжить существование, а этой метке существовать причин я не вижу. Но вопросы в неё затекают с невероятной частотой. Утром заглядывал, было пусто, а сейчас два.

Comment: @D-side тогда есть два других предложения на дубликатство: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5600/176217) и [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2225/176217).